# print different parts of HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have two print buttons on my side, if I click button 1 than part A should be printed of page, if button 2 is clicked part B should be printed but noch part A.

Is there a possibility to do this, "conditional printing"?

```
<button onClick="javascript:window.print()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Print Button 1</button>
<button onClick="javascript:window.print()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Print Button 2</button>
```

Comment: Instead of calling `window.print()` directly, make a call to a function that hides the content you don't want to print, and then all the print function.

Comment: you can use **show()** and **hide()** of jQuery for that.